# How to replace the source file with my own source file (from download or edit) in Xcode?

Tags: c++, c, xcode

I'm using Xcode as an IDLE editor of C language. I downloaded an SDK package from a algorithm competition website and compiled it successfully on the terminal, but now I have a need to compile and run the source .cpp file(that inside the SDK packadge) directly by Xcode, so:

1. Is there a way to replace the CPP source file of command-line-tools project with the CPP source file that I specify the path of it?
2. Or is there a way to creat a new command-line-tools project from the specified path CPP source file?

Answer (score 0):

I've now Solved this problem through the method one whitch says "Is there a way to replace the CPP source file of command-line-tools project with the CPP source file that I specify the path of it?", but still have no idea about method two.
Just creat a symbolink of CPP source file and right-click the project, add the alias to project. Because the "add" is copy in fact, instead of "import" or "open". Only by copying the alias can the purpose of modifying the source file be achieved.